# Review of a not an answer accepted already

Tags: support

I encounter in my review of late answers an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17952792) by the OP which was accepted already by the OP.

It doesn't really answer the question, unless "no news" is an answer, 
I'm not sure if to mark it as not an answer because the OP accepted it

**Edit**

I skipped the review, but I saw some marked it as `No Action Needed`

Comment: Saying something is not supported/impossible is still an answer to a question

Comment: I'm not sure and also can you answer yourself that? in that case I can answer all my questions something as waiting for response

Comment: The answer doesn't say there's no response, or waiting for a response. It's saying there's no support for it. Whether or not that's true is a different story